# If index duplicated then add column value to sum

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

The pandas DF has datetime index with price and volume at that price.

```
                  Last      Volume
Date_Time                      
20160907 070000  1.1249         17
20160907 070001  1.1248         12
20160907 070001  1.1249         15
20160907 070002  1.1248         13
20160907 070002  1.1249         20
```

I want to create a column that keeps a running total(sum) of volume through the sequence if the price repeats. I am trying to create a column that would look like this.

```
Last              Volume                 VolumeCount
1.1249                17                     17
1.1248                12                     12
1.1249                15                     32
1.1248                13                     25
1.1249                20                     52
```

I have been working on different functions and loops and I can't seem to create a column that that isn't a total sum of the group. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Try `DF['VolumeCount'] = DF.groupby('Last')['Volume'].cumsum()`.

Comment: I think you want to only if price is same as previous price.  You have in your example where volume accumulates on each individual price.  @Abdou matches your expected output, but nether match what you actually said.

Comment: Thank You so much! I can't believe I was making it so complicated. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DF['VolumeCount'] = DF.groupby('Last')['Volume'].cumsum()
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to accumulated volume on contiguous sets of same `Last`

consider the `df`

```
                 Last      Volume  
Date_Time         
20160907-70000  1.1249         17
20160907-70001  1.1248         12
20160907-70001  1.1248         15
20160907-70002  1.1248         13
20160907-70002  1.1249         20
```

Then

```
df.Volume.groupby((df.Last != df.Last.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()

Date_Time
20160907-70000    17
20160907-70001    12
20160907-70001    27
20160907-70002    40
20160907-70002    20
Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```